# Retrieve multiple record from listbox to form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I am using MS Access 2016. I have a multi-select form (subform) that I have inserted in my form. I use the multi-select form (subform) to perform selection on the data that I want to select.

I have an "edit" button on my form when will retrieve data from the currently selected row in the multi-select form (subform) to the form. The multi-select form (subform) contains all the fabric purchase order values that are in short text, integer and date/time. Below is the code that runs when the "edit" button is clicked.

```
Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
'check whether there is exists data in list
If Not (Me.Subform.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.Subform.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
'get data to text box control
With Me.Subform.Form.Recordset
Me.txtGLGPO = .Fields("PO")
Me.txtFabricDelivery = .Fields("Date")
Me.txtStyleNO = .Fields("Style No")
Me.txtGLA = .Fields("Lot No")
Me.txtFabrication = .Fields("Fabrication")
Me.txtWidth = .Fields("Fabric Cuttable Width")
Me.txtColour = .Fields("Colour")
Me.txtLbs = .Fields("Our Qty")
Me.txtYds = .Fields("Supplier Qty")
Me.txtFabricDelivery = .Fields("Date")
Me.txtFinishedGoods = .Fields("GSMBeforeWash")
Me.txtGSMsq = .Fields("GMS Per SqYD")
Me.txtPrintedRemarks = .Fields("Remark")
Me.txtFabricWeight = .Fields("Fabric Weight")
Me.txtUnitPrice = .Fields("Unit Price")
Me.txtName1 = .Fields("ShipName")
Me.txtGarmentDelDate = .Fields("Garment Delivery Date")
Me.txtLine = .Fields("Line")
Me.txtPOStatus = .Fields("POStatus")
Me.txtAmendment = .Fields("PO Amend No")
Me.txtGSMAfterWash = .Fields("GSMAfterWash")   
Me.Image97.Picture = Me.txtGarmentSketch & ""
'disable button edit
Me.cmdEdit.Enabled = True
End With
End If
End Sub
```

This work perfectly fine and i have issue with this button.
What I want now is that after selecting the data I want from the multi-select form (subform), I can still click "edit" button to retrieve all the selected data onto the form. The above code can only retrieve only single record value.

PS. I have posted on this forum as well http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2047702
I could not manage to get much more information that can help me in this issue, hence, i posted here as well.

Comment: _The above code can only retrieve only single record value._ Yes. But then: _after selecting the data I want from the multi-select form (subform), I can still click "edit" button to retrieve all the selected data onto the form._ makes no sense. Seems like an overwrite.

Comment: What I mean is that after selecting the data I want from the multi-select form (subform), how can I retrieve and read through all the data that I have selected to my form so that i can edit on some of the data before saving it in the database

Comment: As you have retrieved the data to the form from the subform, you can edit the data in the form. But I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why not edit the data in the subform?

Comment: Also, your title is very confusing. It states listbox but you write about a subform. And how should multiple records be retrieved to a single record in the main form. I can see the UA people are utterly confused too, so you may have to rephrase your question completely.

Comment: Because i will need to perform a calculation to the data on the form before saving it.

Comment: it is actually a muti-select form which i have make into subform so that i can insert under my form to select the data i need.

Comment: Have you considered Form.BeforeUpdate event?

Comment: To begin off, I am actually not very skilled in programming. Hence, please be patience toward me hehe! Hmm, nope as I have no idea how before update event works? I am looking for any method that is able to retrieve and display the multiple records that I have selected onto my form

Answer (score 0):

> It is actually a multi-select form which I have made into subform so
>   that I can insert under my form to select the data I need

Then you could skip all your code, bind both main form and subform to the same recordsource, and - when selecting a record in the subform - set the main form to *filter* on the ID of the selected record.

Comment: by doing that, can i still select the lines of data that i need before retrieving it to the form for editing?

Comment: If the main form is a normal form (single record), only one record can be edited. A continuous record form could display several records, but setting the filter is much more complicated.

Comment: oh, the main form is a normal form. Which explain why i want to use subform to allow me to select the lines of data that i need to retrieve and display on the main form. Do you have any suggestion that can share with me to achieve that?

Comment: You can select one record, get the ID of this, and filter the main form on that ID. That's the simple method.

Comment: I am able to select and retrieve all the data for one record, however i am unable to do that for multiple data